# wp_pagenavi não funciona em category.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Baixei e instalei o Plugin wp_pagenavi eu coloquei no fim do meu código, ele aparece só que não pagina, clicando, seja no 2... 3... ele não pagina, sempre repete os itens de 1 a 10.

Código

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div class="contentCenter">
        <div class="internalContent">
            <h1> <?php echo "Categoria "; single_cat_title(''); ?> </h1>
            <?php query_posts($query_strings . "&order=ASC"); ?>

            <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="postList">
                    <div class="postListImage">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(198, 198)); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p style="font-size:12px; margin-top:4px;">
                        <i>Publicado por <strong><?php the_author(); ?></strong> em <strong> <?php the_time('d/m/Y'); ?></strong></i>
                    </p>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="read_more_link">
                        Continuar Lendo >>
                    </a>
                    <div class="visualClear"></div>
                </div>
            <?php
                endwhile;
                else:
            ?>
                <p class="no-posts-found">Nenhum post encontrado.</p>
            <?php
                endif;
            ?>
        <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

O que eu poderia fazer pra ele funcionar?

*Obs.: Sou novato no Wordpress.*

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isso define o limite que você quer na linha 5:

```
<?php
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 $args = array('posts_per_page' => '8'); 
 query_posts($args . $query_strings . '&order=ASC&paged=' . $paged);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`wp_pagenavi` está falhando porque a sua query está sendo sobrescrita com [`query_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/). A internet vai te dizer o contrário, mas **nunca é uma boa ideia usar query_posts()** porque essa função bagunça todas as variáveis globais do tema e causa esses tipos de problemas.

O plugin está implementado corretamente mas ao invés de chamar `query_posts` na linha 5 as alterações na consulta devem ser feitas no seu arquivo `functions.php` usando o filtro [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts).

Exemplo:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'modifica_query_category');
function modifica_query_category( $query ) {
    // modifica apenas a query principal de arquivos de categoria
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_category() ) {
        // altera a ordem para ascendente
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    } 
}
```

Com isso você elimina a consulta duplicada, melhora a performance do site e corrige os erros de paginação de uma vez só :)